# 1054, "Unknown column 'work_waterlevel.id' in 'field list'" in django

Tags: python, html, django, web-development-server

I am trying to display my mysql data on a HTML page everything is working fine but when i try to display the data from mySQL tohtml page its showing
1054, "Unknown column 'work_waterlevel.id' in 'field list'") this error how to resolve this error
my models.py is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class waterlevel(models.Model):
    time=models.DateTimeField()
    status=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=6)
```

the traceback is as follows

```
 File "C:\Users\siddhant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\siddhant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\siddhant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\siddhant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\siddhant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'work_waterlevel.id' in 'field list'")
```

its showing i have error in my view.py file my view.py file is as follows

```
def generate(request):
    
    b=request.POST['level']
    a=request.POST['status']
    output=run([sys.executable,'C:\\Users\\siddhant\\Desktop\\internship\\indicator\\work\\water.py',b,a],stdout=PIPE,text=True)
    event_list=waterlevel.objects.all()
    
    return render(request,'result.html',{'event':event_list})
```

anyone can suggest how I can send my MySQL data to the result.html page

Comment: Please share the full traceback and the corresponding view.

Comment: Did you properly migrate the database?

Comment: yes i have properly migrated  the datbase

Comment: Is this a table that you created via a Django migration or was it an existing table that you created the model to access?

Comment: I created this table with django migration

Comment: Have you recently modified the model? Maybe changed the primary key? For the `id` column to not be present I imagine you must have created the model with a custom primary key

Comment: No i didnt modified it k just simply write the models code and made migrations after that nthing else

Comment: Did you apply the migrations after creating them? `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yess after creating i applied migration

Answer (score 1):

Try this way for fix without spending time:

```
1 - Delete migrations files
2 - Clean database (delete tables or recreate database)
3 - run makemigration
4 - run migrate
5 - run createsuperuser
```